# Hover effect problems using Internet Explorer 10, IE10

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, compatibility

I´m trying my proyect in all web browsers, the web page works perfectly in IE9 and IE11, but i don't understand what is happening in Internet Explorer 10.

If you try my website when you put mouse on sections, the over effects not working with IE10.

[Click here to open my proyect.](http://ecoavantis.com/iucn/)

Thank you;)

Comment: it is working fine for me in ie10.

Comment: it works me too in IE10 (native, not pseudo-IE10 from developer tools).

Comment: The client says that not work in IE10, and I download this version, I´m sure that my website don´t works in IE10.

Comment: everything is working fine right now

Comment: Why website don´t work in my web browser? and in the client web browser  too.

Comment: Silly questions, have you clear browser's cache? Any error in IE console? Don't you emulate older IE (8) version? That's said, your website works as expected for me too on IE10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the "Standars configuration" in IE10, you can see if you press F12. I think it can solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your doctype is malformed, triggering [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) in IE10. Replace your current:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
```

with the proper:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

and make sure there is no whitespace (like blank lines) preceding it.

Always validate your html!

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fecoavantis.com%2Fiucn

Error output at time of posting:

[image]